# DocIO throw an error when convert from html to sfdt

Tags: html, .net, syncfusion

I switched from my old Primeface RichEditor to syncfusion WordEditor, and I use the bellow class to transform from html to sdft

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import com.syncfusion.docio.FormatType;
import com.syncfusion.docio.WordDocument;
import com.syncfusion.ej2.wordprocessor.WordProcessorHelper;

public class SFDTAdapter {
    
    public static String sfdtToRtf(String sfdt) throws Exception {
        return WordProcessorHelper.save(sfdt, com.syncfusion.ej2.wordprocessor.FormatType.Rtf).toString();
    }
    
    public static String rtfToSfdt(String rtf) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = rtf.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        WordDocument document = new WordDocument(stream, FormatType.Rtf);
        String sfdt =  WordProcessorHelper.load(document);
        document.close();
        stream.close();
        return sfdt;
    }
    
    
    public static String htmlToSfdt(String html) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        WordDocument document = new WordDocument(stream, FormatType.Html);
        String sfdt = WordProcessorHelper.load(document);
        document.close();
        stream.close();
        return sfdt;
    }
    
    public static String sfdtToHtml(String sfdt) throws Exception {
        return WordProcessorHelper.save(sfdt, com.syncfusion.ej2.wordprocessor.FormatType.Html).toString();
    }
}
```

However, when I process old registers I get the following issue "The element type 'br' must be terminated by the matching end-tag ". According to what I readed, this is because DocIO validates that the content follow the format xhtml 1. Is there a way to say to DocIO that ignore errors, or doesn't verify that format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding - I get the following issue "The element type 'br' must be terminated by the matching end-tag:**

The input HTML string is not well formatted HTML (‘br’ element doesn’t have an end tag).

Essential [Word library](https://www.syncfusion.com/document-processing/word-framework/net-core/word-library) (DocIO) supports only well formatted HTML (the given HTML content must be in accordance with rules or standards of XHTML 1.0 format). To resolve this issue, please use well-formatted HTML like ‘br’ element has proper start and end tags in the HTML string.

**Regarding - Is there a way to say to DocIO that ignore errors, or doesn't verify that format?**

No. There is no way to ignore that errors and verify that format in DocIO library. To resolve the issue, please use well-formatted HTML in DocIO like HTML string that has proper element’s start and end tags.

Comment: In fact the issue was related to a previous not well formatted image, I mean it was something like this <img src="" style="""/>. Thank you very much for your help.